# Compare two number fields in SharePoint 2013 list and display a message

Tags: validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need help. I need to compare two number fields in SharePoint and if the columns do not have equal value system should show the message before saving the item in the same list. For Example

Field1 = 1000.00
Field2 = 900.00

In above, the system should check the and validate both the columns and if they are not equal show a message "Values Should be equal" before saving the item

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to list settings->list validation.

```
=IF(Field1=Field2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]